# Snippets: Detect if a snippet prefix is used in a string or regular javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, jss

I want to build a tool to help me do stuff faster in my project. For that, I want to use the snippet functionality.
Is it possible to know if a snippet prefix was used in string quotes or regular javascript code so for example:

```
'prefix + tab' (with quotes) -> outputs one thing
 prefix + tab  (no quotes)   -> outputs different thing.
```

so that:

```
'bgc + tab'   -> 'background-color: $1'
 prefix + tab ->  backgroundColor: $1
```

I hope my question makes sense :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable suggestions in strings. Add this to your *settings.json*:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
  },
```

And then define your snippet:

```
"Background Color": {
        "prefix": "bgc",
        "body": [
            "background-color: $1"
        ],
        "description": "Background Color"
    },
```

You can create your snippet by selecting **User Snippets** **under File > Preferences (Code > Preferences on macOS)** and select the language (JavaScript).

Comment: The thing is in most cases it would be like this

    `const Body = styled.div'
        bgc -> background-color: $1
    ';`

    `const styles = {
        bgc -> backgroundColor: $1
    }`

Makes sense?

Comment: So the one is styled components string notation (react), and the other is regular object notation styling.

Comment: I guess you would like single prefix to inject different snippet depending on the context it's currently in (in/ out of quoted string). The solution above works, but only for 'bgc' prefix. You should type `bgc` before opening quote, the snippet will inject it.

Comment: Exactly! The problem occurs when I want to have multiple of those written out for me in a single block of quotes. Might be a bit more complicated than I first anticipated

Comment: @Darko Updated answer. Does this help?